# Why can't I replace the URL of these incoming JSON'd images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I've got this JS code that pulls JSON from a php file. That works. What I'm trying to do is change JSON values before they're put into the DOM to replace image URLs with lower-res images. You'll see the beginning of this in the IF statement calling the **mobile()** function

Here we go:

```
$.post(url, project, function(data, textStatus) {
  $(data.tags).each(function(i, item){
    projectTags += "<span class='project-tag'>"+item+"</span>";
  });

  $(data.slides).each(function(i, item){

    if ((mobile() == true && $(window).width() <= 680)){
      if (i != 0){
        console.log('Before' +item);
        var newItem = JSON.stringify(item);
        $(newItem).replace('.png','-lofi.png');
        console.log(newItem);

        console.log('After' + item);
      }
    }

    projectImages += "<div class=\"slide-container\">" + item + "</div>";
    console.log(projectImages);
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    btnAbout.removeClass('active');
    sectionDetail
      .attr('data-id', data.id)
      .find('.project-name').html(data.name).end()
      .find('.project-year').html(data.year).end()
      .find('.project-agency').html(data.agency).end()
      .find('.project-details').html(data.details).end()
      .find('.project-tags').html(projectTags).end()
      .find('#slideshow').html(projectImages);
}, "json");
```

What gives? ALL I want to do is replace the URL of JSON value if it's a mobile device smaller than an iPad.

**EDIT: Fixed by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2241552/james)! Thanks buddy! FINAL CODE BELOW.**

```
$.post(url, project, function(data, textStatus) {
  $(data.tags).each(function(i, item){
    projectTags += "<span class='project-tag'>"+item+"</span>";
  });

  $(data.slides).each(function(i, item){
    var loFi = JSON.stringify(item);
    if ((mobile() == true && $(window).width() <= 680)){
      if (i != 0){
        loFi = loFi.replace(/(.png)/g,'-lofi.png')
        loFi = $.parseJSON(loFi);
        item = loFi;
      }
    }
    projectImages += "<div class=\"slide-container\">" + item + "</div>";

  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    btnAbout.removeClass('active');
    sectionDetail
      .attr('data-id', data.id)
      .find('.project-name').html(data.name).end()
      .find('.project-year').html(data.year).end()
      .find('.project-agency').html(data.agency).end()
      .find('.project-details').html(data.details).end()
      .find('.project-tags').html(projectTags).end()
      .find('#slideshow').html(projectImages);
}, "json");
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(data.slides).each(function(i, item){

var newItem = JSON.stringify(item);  <-- Add this early

if ((mobile() == true && $(window).width() <= 680)){
  if (i != 0){
    console.log('Before' +item);
    newItem = newItem.replace(/(.png)/g,'-lofi.png');
    console.log(newItem);

    console.log('After' + item);
  }
}
```

You are still adding the regular item here? any changes you made to item are not reflected.

```
projectImages += "<div class=\"slide-container\">" + item + "</div>";
```

change to

```
projectImages += "<div class=\"slide-container\">" + newItem + "</div>";
```

Comment: You were the closest to being spot on (we needed to turn the string back into an object in this particular instance) so you get the check. I'll update my question to reflect the final code! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
var newItem = JSON.stringify(item);
newItem = newItem.replace('.png','-lofi.png');
```

You're forgetting to assign the result of 'replace' to your variable and you don't need to wrap newItem in $(..), replace is a `String` object function.

PS. You probably don't need to `stringify` either. Isn't your item already a String?